# Tomcat error with deployment

Tags: spring, tomcat, war

I am trying to deploy a war file to tomcat 6.0.27. This war file has spring conf and java beans and also the regular html etc. This war file deploys successfully on a tomcat installed on a windows platform. However when trying to deploy to Linux, following is the error that is displayed in the tomcat logs: (and the application is not deployed)

```
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
LifecycleException:  Error initializaing :  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The archive [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/afghlcustomer.war!/] is malformed and will be ignored: an entry contains an illegal path [/]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:905)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1359)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1475)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:645)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doPut(ManagerServlet.java:432)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:640)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:558)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How do I resolve this issue? Where do I start?

Comment: How are you building the WAR file?

Comment: @Franklin I am building the war file using ant and ivy. Would you like to see the script?

Comment: As a quick fix, how about you deploy the exploded folder directly rather than the WAR file. Atleast you will know its working on Linux.

Comment: @Franklin Our linux admin was exploding the file in the webapps folder manually but then it started clashig with another spring project. It would try to look up the controller from another webapp.

Comment: Guys issue has been fixed. It was in the ANT WAR target. A prefix defined as follows: /WEB-INF-classes/... was causing an issue. As WEB-INF is in the root no need to put a "/" at the start. Just called it directly as WEB-INF/classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have hit on a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50737) with the JVM , but I am pretty sure the exploded folder should work.

Comment: I just tried this. The projects get deployed but then as I said earlier they start clashing with each other. one project tries to call the controller of another spring project.

Comment: I am not having any such issues on windows platform.

Comment: Am sure you would already know this, but each project has its own folder in the webapp directory. right!! Also are you using Spring Webservices? I too had a weird conflict once when two Spring WS apps were deployed on the same Tomcat.

Comment: Well I have resolved this issue now. It was the way I was scanning for controllers in the base package. I used a * instaed of actually specifying the base package like com.xxx. Anyways thanks for your help @Franklin. I did deploy it in the way recomended by you, for now till the remote deployment script starts working.

Comment: Good it worked out. Let us know when the remote deployment works.

Comment: I will I am still on it buddy.