# Failed to start war in tomcat caused by IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, tomcat

Environment info

- Tomcat: 8.5.9
- JDK: 1.8.0_112-b16

The war file can be deployed using Tomcat Web Application Manager successfully, but failed to be started. The war file can be decompress just fine so I think it's a valid zip file.

The detailed exception is

```
16-Mar-2017 14:34:11.792 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log FAIL - Application at context path /propertyMS-1.0 could not be started
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/propertyMS-1.0]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1307)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:669)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:217)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:591)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:319)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:789)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1437)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The archive [jar:file:/Users/bruce/apache-tomcat-8.5.9/webapps/propertyMS-1.0.war!/] is malformed and will be ignored: an entry contains an illegal path [./] which was not expanded to [/Users/bruce/apache-tomcat-8.5.9/webapps/propertyMS-1.0] since that is outside of the defined docBase [/Users/bruce/apache-tomcat-8.5.9/webapps/propertyMS-1.0/]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.expand(ExpandWar.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.fixDocBase(ContextConfig.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.beforeStart(ContextConfig.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:149)
    ... 35 more
```

Thanks.

*Update*:

As suggested I expanded the war into a folder then deployed the folder to same tomcat server and it works. I'm not sure what's wrong with the war file. It can be decompressed so it should be a valid zip file, at least.

Comment: Maybe a dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117526/tomcat-error-with-deployment

Comment: Try to expand the war in the webapp-folder and restart the tomcat.

Comment: @TobiasOtto It works if I put the expanded folder into the webapp folder. Still not sure what the problem is with the war file.

Comment: The stacktrace message is clear enough. What do you not understand about it?

Comment: @Raedwald I'm not quite sure what "an entry contains an illegal path [./]" means here.

Comment: how did you create the war file?

Comment: @Yazan We have some shell and gradle scripts to build the war file.

Comment: all i can say is, make sure it includes only files from the project path, and when added to the war file, i think there is some option to include original path structure (don't use that), because when tomcat try to extract the archive into that path (out of webapps/project dir) it will fail... could be this ?! try to use a command to list archive entries and see if any of the entries have a path out of project dir

Comment: @Yazan I was thinking about the same thing but I can only test the solution tomorrow. It seems tomcat will validate the folder structure while expanding the war file. We added some extra files into the war lately. Thanks for the information. Please make it an answer if you want. Maybe one day other people run into the same issue can learn from this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all i can say is, make sure it includes only files from the project path.

when you add file to the the war i think there is some option to include original path structure (don't use that), because when tomcat try to extract the archive into that path (out of webapps/project dir) it will fail...

try to use a command to list archive entries and see if any of the entries have a path out of project dir

Comment: In our case the problem was caused by our build scripts which added a hidden directory into the war file which contains some Javascript and dependency files.